# I tried to edit a gnome menu extension and all extensions stopped working. Extension manager no longer functions. How can I fix this?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, gnome-shell-extension

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and have been using it successfully for quite a while.

I had previously modified the appearance of the desktop using gnome extensions. Frankly, it ended up looking something like Windows 7, showing a clock, a taskbar, a categorized application menu, open windows along the bottom of the screen, etc.

Recently, I successfully installed a piece of linux-native commercial software. The new software was in the menu, but I wanted to place it in a specific category. I used either "Main Menu" or "Menu Editor" to attempt to place the new software menu entry in an already established menu category. After this, none of the gnome extensions work. If I try to use gnome's "Extension Manager" program, it doesn't show most of the installed extensions and won't let me turn any on or off. If I do so, the Extension Manager makes me log in twice and then shows no changes.

I would really like to restore the appearance of my desktop to the way I had set it up. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can repair my system? I'd like to avoid a complete reinstall but I will do that if I need to. To avoid a complete reinstall, could I somehow reinstall gnome to repair the damage that it apparently suffered?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Not sure what you did, but just using Menu editor cannot have caused this. This to me smells as a corruption of your file system, where configuration files/directories in the home directory may have been damaged or became missing. You did not have an unexpected power outage? Such symptoms may also be caused by a failing hard drive or other faulty system components (e.g. hard drive controler).